# Get label text extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, label

Does anyone help me how to get label text?, It run if I use `setText()` but when I want to get it,I've tried with `getText()`, `getLabel()` it doesn't run. So I need help if you have an idea. Thanks

```
var lbl = {
    xtype: 'label',
    id: 'lblId',
    text: 'Hello world!'
};
new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    items: [lbl,
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            listeners: {
                click: function () {
                    var label = Ext.get('lblId');
                    console.log(label.getText());
                }
            },
            text: 'click here'
        }]
});
```

Comment: add some code here which you tried ?

Comment: what is the version of extjs?

Comment: Try with `label.getHtml()`, and if you wanna put html code in there, use html config instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the component.

```
console.log(label.component.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
App.label.getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your click listener function:

```
            var label = Ext.getCmp('lblId');
            label.setText('the new text');
            console.log(label.text);
```

This will get *label* as an Ext Js component and then you can change the text using `.setText()` and retrieve it using `.text`.

see Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jkb

Answer (score 0):

You can try these three ways. First by directly accessing `text`, and the other forms is accessing the label's `DOM` object.

```js
var lbl = {
    xtype: 'label',
    id: 'lblId',
    text: 'Hello world!'
};

new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    items: [lbl,
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            listeners: {
                click: function () {
                    var label = Ext.getCmp('lblId');
                    console.log('Way 1: ' + label.text);
                    console.log('Way 2: ' + label.el.dom.innerHTML);    
                    console.log('Way 3: ' + label.getEl().dom.innerHTML);
                }
            },
            text: 'click here'
        }]
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css")/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
this.findById('lblId');
```

In AEM we can get the extjs label widget by

```
 dialog.findById("lblId");
```